# HackerRank Big Sorting segmentation Fault in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault

I have a question about the [BigSorting task](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem) from HackerRank.

My code successfully runs all tests except 3. (I located files on which my program does not work under the names input03.txt, input04.txt and input05.txt on my google drive. Here is the link to the drive.) https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1psno2RbeYXX5ohHjs5BWke6E-K2cJl-3

My program crashes with a "Segmentation fault" error. I’ve been sitting for 2 hours and can’t understand what the mistake is. This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I apologize right away if I did something wrong.

Here is the code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool isShorter(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    if (s1.size() != s2.size())
    {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); ++i)
        {
            int x = s1[i] - '0';
            int y = s2[i] - '0';
            if (x != y)
            {
                return x < y;
            }
        }
    }   
    return true;
}

std::vector<std::string> bigSorting(std::vector<std::string> unsorted) 
{
    std::sort(unsorted.begin(), unsorted.end(), isShorter);
    return unsorted;
}
```

Comment: Compiling your code with debug symbols and then running it through a debugger might help.

Comment: Please show a full [repro] of the problem. That means code, including a `main`, that can be compiled and executed as is. Without it, while I see an error in your code, I cannot tell whether it is the only one and responsible for the segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you answer! Next time I will show full code, including main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function given to `std::sort` is supposed to induce a *strict* weak ordering on the elements in the iterator range, see [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [*Compare* requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) and [*strict weak ordering* on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Your `isShorter` induces an order that is not strict. In particular it does not have the property that `isShorter(x, x) == false` for all `x`.

The problem is that you return `true` when you cannot find either string to come before or after the other in the order, but you should return `false`.

The function is supposed to model `<`, not `<=`.

Whether this is the cause of the segmentation fault is unclear since you haven't given a full code example, but violating the `std::sort` requirements does cause undefined behavior.